# Pass List of models to controller ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: view, model, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view where user can enter some data. But problem is this:
Let's say you have 3 text box on view. Every time user can fill multiple times this 3 text boxes. To clarify, let's say user fills this 3 text boxes and press button which adds on form again these 3 text boxes. Now when user clicks submit this form is sent to controller, but how do I sent List of models as parameter. 
My architecture for this problem is something like this:

**MyModel**

```
public int ID { get;set; }

public string Something { get; set; }

/*This three textboxes can user set multiple times*/
/*Perhaps i Can create new model with these properties and then 
/*put List of that model as property here, but how to fill that list inside view ??*/                   
public string TextBoxOneValue { get; set; }   
public string TextBoxTwoValue { get; set; }
public string TextBoxThreeValue { get; set; }
```

Now, i was thinking that i Create PartialView with this 3 text boxes, and then when user clicks button on view another PartialView is loaded.

And now, let's say I have Two partial views loaded, and user clicks submit, how that I pass list with values of these 3 text boxes to controller ??

Comment: i think this is what you want...

Answer (score 0):

You can  achieve above functionality this way :

**View :-**

Just add as many input fields as you want but when dynamically adding the inputs make sure they are named and indexed correctly as shown :-

```
<input type="text" name="[0].textdata" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="[1].textdata" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="[2].textdata" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="[3].textdata" value="4" />
..........
..........
```

**Controller :-**

```
Public ActionResult MyControllerAction(List<string> textdata) // here textdata will have list of posted input values.
{....}
```

Above shown example is with simple html input types (which is simple to implement) but if you want strongly typed textboxes and add them dynamically then see this link :- http://www.techiesweb.net/asp-net-mvc3-dynamically-added-form-fields-model-binding/